# Invalid object name 'dbo.stream'

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have made a website which works perfectly on the `Local` machine but when i uploaded it on the `web server` it is giving an error

> Invalid object name 'dbo.stream'.

**Code**

```
private void BindStreamDropDown() { 
    string query = " Select * from stream"; 
    DataTable dt = c.getData(query); 
    DDLStream.DataSource = dt; 
    DDLStream.DataValueField = "StreamId"; 
    DDLStream.DataTextField = "stream"; 
    DDLStream.DataBind(); 
    DDLStream.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "")); 
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have - code, snippets, something. OTTOMH, sound like you jave some URL issues. Do you have `localhost` somewhere in your code?

Comment: put the code in question chawala

Comment: verify your table must be stream in dbo schema and also verify you database name on server

Comment: That is a sql server error stating there is no View or Table with the name Stream associated with the dbo schema in that database. So you are pointing to the wrong database, or that table/view exists under a different schema (not dbo), or that table or view does not exist  as in maybe you misspelled it (streams instead of stream) or it was never created to begin with.

Comment: the table name is 
>stream
database name is 
>STech

the website is [link](http://www.stechacademy.com)

Comment: i also tried table name without 

>dbo.
`select * from Stream`
as well as 
`select * from dbo.Stream;`

now the question is should there be any other prefix attached to the table name when it have tobe running on the web server?
@igor @NazirUllah

Comment: i had faced this issue once on production,The cause was the prefix `dbo`.I guess some server has its own db prefix, so i removed all the dbo part wherever i used table and SP names.

Comment: @NawazKhan check your connection string. Probably on local machine your user account has "default database" defined equal to your working db and you are getting there without defining DB explicitly in connection string. While on remote server "default db" is not set and you are falling into `master`.

Comment: connection string = `"Data Source=(IP address of my DB);Integrated Security=False;User ID=USERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096"`. Any suggestions what it should be for **remote server** @IvanStarostin @vijaygautam

Comment: @NawazKhan - The prefix is the schema name, you should read up on what that means [SQL Server Best Practices – Implementation of Database Object Schemas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095(v=sql.100).aspx). You will have to lookas it could be `there is no View or Table with the name Stream associated with the dbo schema in that database. So you are pointing to the wrong database, or that table/view exists under a different schema (not dbo), or that table or view does not exist as in maybe you misspelled it (streams instead of stream) or it was never created to begin with'.

Comment: About your connection string, you should have the database name in that connection string otherwise it will go to the one associated as the default db for that user like `master`. `Data Source=(IP address of my DB);Integrated Security=False;User ID=USERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;Initial Catalog=YOURDATABASENAMEHERE;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096`

Comment: @NawazKhan https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: thanks everyone for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment above you are missing the database that you want to connect to in your connection string. If you do not provide this and do not update the SqlConnection with the database then the user's default database will be used, if you have never set this database it will default to `master`. The missing part is:

```
Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE
```

There are plenty of ways tools, web sites, and also code to help you build a proper connection string. Examples:

- http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/sql-connection-string/
- https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/ - *posted in comments by Ivan Starostin*

With this added part to the connection string you provided in the comments it would look similar to this:

```
Data Source=(IP address of my DB);Integrated Security=False;User ID=USERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;Initial Catalog=YOURDATABASENAMEHERE;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096
```

*Note: the order of the connection string parts does not matter*

Comment: **Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_HERE** this solved the problem thanks alot
@Igor

Answer (score 0):

your connection is wrong you must have db Name in connection otherwise it first attempt from master db , where it no found any table

please update your C. string as

```
Data Source=(IP address of my DB);Integrated Security=False;User ID=USERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;Initial Catalog=YOURDATABASENAMEHERE;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096
```

Comment: i try to login you site it give error as The network path was not found

Comment: my i use`Data Source=(IP address of my DB);Integrated Security=False;User ID=USERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;Initial Catalog=YOURDATABASENAMEHERE;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096` the `connection.open();` executes that means it establishes connection to the database successfully but when i change `Data Source=STech;Integrated Security=False;User ID=USERNAME;Password=MYPASSWORD;Initial Catalog=YOURDATABASENAMEHERE;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096` the `connection.open()` is also not able to execute which means changing the DATASOURCE is not helpful@NazirUllah

Comment: i have my DB in **myLittleAdmin** which i got when i purchased my hosting and domain from them